# WPF Global Style to be applied to multiple control template

Tags: wpf

I have global style which I share across several projects in my application. But when any XAML has Data Templates these styles are not applied. Is there a way in which these can be applied without making any changes to the datatemplate resources.

Comment: Yes there is a way but first post us more code please.

Answer (score 0):

Good you have explained briefly.

The problem here the key specified for the style in xaml. Dont specify any keys. If you specify key for the style, it will only be applied for the corresponding controls which asks for the style explicitly.

So now you style should look as below(just removing **x:Key**).

```
 <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
</Style>
```

If you want to apply styles based on Keys then ur Datatemplate's textBlock code should be like below

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Currcode}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
```

Comment: But what I have observed that when though I do not have a key for the style. Still it does not get applied to the controls present in a datatemplate.

Comment: No it still doesn't get applied.

Answer (score 0):

oh yes i faced the issue earlier make the Data template not to be part of  the same resource.
ie

```
<userControl>
 <USerControl.Resources>
  **<style is placed here>**
 </USerControl.Resources>
 <Grid>
 <Grid.Resources>
      **<Add the Data template here>**
 </Grid.Resources>
```

I am really not sure why Merged REsource dictionary and data template kept in same USerControl.Resources doesnt work properly

we always use styles in the same manner as you have posted for our controls in data template and control template .